# Ошибка импорта Dispatcher и executor из aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, импорт

Только начала разбираться в программировании телеботов, не получается импортировать Dispatcher и executor.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram_utils import executor
bot=Bot(token="...")
dp=Dispatcher(bot)
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_message(message:types.Message):
    chat_id=message.chat.id
    text='hOW ARE YOU?'
    sent_message= await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
    print(sent_message.to_python())
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Пишет, что ошибка импорта:

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatcher' from partially initialized module 'aiogram' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблеммой но не помог ни один из предложенных способов решения. Windows 11
aiogram 3.0.0b5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я ввела так, и все заработало

```
import aiogram
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
```

Comment: Не получилось( Пишет ошибку:                                                                                                                   
from aiogram import Bot, types
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from 'aiogram'